# How to install Woocommerce without plugin?

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I followed this guide https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Then I installed a Woocommerce folder inside of my theme folder and added some lines in functions.php

```
    function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
        add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', array(
            'thumbnail_image_width' => 150,
            'single_image_width'    => 300,

            'product_grid'          => array(
                'default_rows'    => 3,
                'min_rows'        => 2,
                'max_rows'        => 8,
                'default_columns' => 4,
                'min_columns'     => 2,
                'max_columns'     => 5,
            ),
        ) );
    }
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

And I moved files from template folder to parent folder...

I went to admin panel and nothing happens...

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Castiblanco Asking users to find and install Woocommerce as plugin it's kinda ridiculous.

Comment: Also check this: https://wordimpress.com/how-to-easily-require-plugins-for-your-wordpress-themes/ you can suggest users recommend plugins after they activate your theme.

Comment: Note that 100 plugins is just as slow as 100 plugins that have had their comments deleted and inserted into the theme in a "how to do X without a plugin" article. People say lots of plugins is slow because doing 100 things is slow. Doing those 100 things in the theme is still going to be slow. The correct answer is to do less stuff, not to do it in the theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that.

From the question's title, it kind of seems you think WooCommece is not a plugin, and you install it using a plugin, but the thing is that WooCommerce is a plugin.

You are following a guide called **Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme**, doing that you are only doing so, not installing WooCommerce without a plugin. (sounds funny when you actually say that)

There shouldn't be an issue if you simply install it and use it like the rest of the word.

Comment: Then how do you force to install woocommerce plugin for this theme? I wouldn't like to ask users to find and install woocommerce by themselves because it's bad practice.

Comment: That's a different question, a good one, recommended reading: https://www.wpexplorer.com/woocommerce-compatible-theme/, and search for **How to make my WordPress theme Woocommerce compatible**, you will have lots of things to read.

Comment: Is there a way to integrate woocommerce payment api? I already created posts of each product using different `register_post_type();`... I wouldn't like to repeat the products with woocommerce.

Comment: I am not really following you, do you install WooCommerce? If so, what are you trying to achieve? why do you have to use register_post_type()?

Comment: Why are you talking about the payment api when you’re creating a theme. Themes should have nothing to do with payments.

Comment: @Castiblanco There are some frameworks to integrate payment terminal for different countries require Woocommerce, I found nothing for pure Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t really want to do that for numerous reasons - security being numero uno. However, you could automatically install the plugin for them with the theme install (not the way I recommend, but if you want to do it this way, check out http://tgmpluginactivation.com/).

You could also check for the plugin and if not installed, put up a nag message letting the user know the theme won’t work without that plugin installed. This is the route I’d recommend you take.